# Magento product custom option default value should be name of the customer

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, custom-options, default

I'm creating a store in **magento 1.7.0.2**

Courses are **virtual products** that can be bought. When buying you sign up for a course.

One customer can buy courses for other people. I've set a **custom option**, text field, for a product where the customer is supposed to write the name of the person attending the course.

In most cases the customer buys the course for himself so I want the **custom option** to have a default value which is the **customers name (if signed in)**.

I want this to be visible when the customer is viewing the product so that he can change it if needed.

**How can this be done?**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the right way to do it, But it will work in your case.

First create a custom option ie: Text Field. Now using firebug note the `id` of that field. In my case it was `options_2_text`.

Now goto `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and place this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $field = document.getElementById('options_2_text');
    $field.value = "<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $name = $customer->getName();
    echo $name;
} ?>";
</script>
```

Here on first line `$field = document.getElementById('options_2_text');` instead of `options_2_text` you should put the id which you noted from firebug.

Comment: Thanks Dexter. This'll work on a certain field. I have these (same) fields in several products but since in each product they're custom options they're all given a different ID.. too many of them...

Comment: I am sorry i haven't tried it. Let me know if you get it working